# embed pone lenta mi página web

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo un embed que se activa con un modal

```
<div class='modal' id='ver'><embed 
   src='www.miweb.com/form' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'/></div>
```

lo que pasa es que se pone lenta mi página en el sentido en el que voy haciendo scroll en la página y pareciera que se queda pegada, como si primero bajara otra web y la mía despúes, ¿que hago? será el embed? como lo soluciono?

Comment: Lo que describes es básicamente lo que está pasando. Con `embed` integras un contenido externo en tu página, en este caso otra página. Al ponerle un alto y ancho de 100% ocupará toda la ventana, por lo que primero se hará scroll dentro de el `embed` y luego dentro de tu página (igual que ocurre con los `iframe`). Para solucionarlo debes pensar en cómo quieres diseñar la página. Si es un formulario propio, ¿realmente tienes que usar `embed`? ¿por qué no poner el formulario con código desde el servidor o usando JavaScript? ¿tienes limitaciones de algún tipo?

Comment: Tengo el formulario en otro servidor, lo que sucede es que lo llamo con el embed, porque va ser visto en una página de presentación de un programa, entonces para no mandar a las personas a otra web lo tengo todo así

Comment: Esa información debería ir en la pregunta (a ser posible con algo más de código). ¿Puedes usar JavaScript/AJAX para cargar el formulario de un servidor en el otro? ¿o aunque sea para enviar los resultados?

Comment: sí, puedo usar ambos.

Comment: Prueba a hacer eso entonces, carga el formulario directamente en tu página (sin `embed`) y manda los datos via AJAX. De ese modo tendrás todo en tu propia página y no tendrás que hacer dos scrolles diferentes.

Comment: y como se hace eso?

Comment: Buena pregunta. Para eso creo que haría falta más información en tu pregunta (¿cómo es el formulario? ¿cómo se trata en el servidor? etc). Otra opción sería usar un `iframe` (o el mismo `embed`) y ajustar el alto del marco al alto del formulario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisamente pasa eso. Tu página está haciendo una petición incrustada y cuando tu página llega a la petición, el procesamiento del HTML para hasta que esta se descarga.

Para darte una respuesta mejor, deberías dar más detalles del formulario. Es un formulario HTML? Entonces usa `<iframe>` en vez de `<embed>`. `<embed>` es más idóneo para otro tipo de aplicaciones (ejemplo, tu formulario es un objeto .swf (flash por ejemplo), e incluso en ese caso, te recomendaría usar `<object>`

Lo más eficiente sería usar AJAX, como te ha dicho otro usuario, pero solo si tienes control sobre las cabeceras de los servidores, para evitarte problemas de control de acceso (CORS). Como lo implementas va a depender mucho de tu setup (qué versión de especificación de ECMAScript estás usando, si usas algún framework o plugin o no, etc.)